# Quine's quasi quotation

Tags: quine, syntax

I would like to know what's the point of Quine's quasi-quotation, that is the use of angle brackets. How does they differ from ordinary commas quotation?

Comment: See Wiki's entry.

Comment: In a nutshell, the possibility to perform substitution in it.